# Find template / object in image using Open CV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm working on project related to medical tests, in which I need to find out if test is  positive, negative or invalid.
below is example of my project needs

1. input image

[image]

2. check for test result like in below image

[image]

I have tried template detection example using OpenCV but its not accurate.

below is code which i tried

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv.imread('s4.jpg', 0)
img2 = img.copy()
template = cv.imread('sub-2.jpeg', 0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
# All the 6 methods for comparison in a list
methods = ['cv.TM_CCOEFF', 'cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED', 'cv.TM_CCORR',
           'cv.TM_CCORR_NORMED', 'cv.TM_SQDIFF', 'cv.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED']
for meth in methods:
    img = img2.copy()
    method = eval(meth)
    # Apply template Matching
    res = cv.matchTemplate(img, template, method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(res)
    # If the method is TM_SQDIFF or TM_SQDIFF_NORMED, take minimum
    if method in [cv.TM_SQDIFF, cv.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]:
        top_left = min_loc
    else:
        top_left = max_loc

    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
    cv.rectangle(img, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
    plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(res, cmap='gray')
    plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.suptitle(meth)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm copying my comment from that [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68313297/11089932): Template matching isn't able to achieve, what you want. It can only find (more or less) exact occurrences of a specific template in some image. It's neither scale or rotation invariant, nor to any other even more complex transforms. You actually want to detect red lines in specific places from, at best, similar looking products with arbitrary(?) backgrounds. Do you understand, that this can be a very challenging task? You'll most likely need advanced methods like neural networks or similar.

Comment: What about doing Canny edge detection to find the rectangle inside of which you have the red lines. Then threshold on red using cv2.inRange() and find how many red lines are found from the threshold inside the Canny edge box.

Comment: thanks all for suggestions, i'm able to resolve this using edge detection to find out test result box then detected no of horizontal lines to get result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks all for suggestions, i'm able to resolve this using edge detection to find out test result box then detected no of horizontal lines to get result.